# how to create an overload operator for adding a new element to the beginning or end of a vector с++

Tags: c++, vector, overloading

First I would like to apologize for the quality of my code, I'm just learning.
I have a university assignment.

String concatenation and adding one character to a string (like
on the left and on the right). Implement using overloading
the operator.

The question is this:
I need to implement two overloads (operator+)
First: adding one element to the end of the vector ( + 'e', ​​for example ).
Second: adding an element to the beginning of the vector ('e' + , for example).

I have problems in order to implement the second part of the assignment.
I searched similar questions on stackoverflow, but they did not help me much.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class String
{
private:
public:
    vector<T> ptr_string;

    String() // default value constructor (empty string)
    {
        ptr_string.push_back('\0');
    }

    String(const String& other) // copy constructor of the same type
    {
        int n = other.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ptr_string.push_back(other.ptr_string[i]);
        }
    }

    String(T symbol, int n) // n times repeated value constructor
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            ptr_string.push_back(symbol);
        }
    }

    String(String&& a) // move constructor
        : ptr_string(a.ptr_string)
    {
        a.ptr_string = nullptr;
    }

    int getLength() const
    {
        return ptr_string.size();
    }

    void printString() const
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ptr_string.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << ptr_string[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    template <typename T2>
    auto operator+(T2 b)
    {
        ptr_string.push_back(b);
        return ptr_string;
    }

    auto operator+(String const& a)
    {
        ptr_string.push_back(a);
        return ptr_string;
    }
};


int main()
{
    String<char> P = String<char>('P', 10);

    P + 'e';
    P.printString();
    'e' + P;
    P.printString();
}
```

I tried to pass a reference to a vector as a parameter, but I ran into a problem that this is most likely not the right solution.

```
auto operator+( String const& a)
{
    ptr_string.push_back(a);
    return ptr_string;
}

String<char> P = String<char>( 'P', 10);
'e' + P;
P.printString();
```

expected result: `ePPPPPPPPPP`

Comment: there is no operator for `'e' + String` in your code. When implemented as member, `this` is always the left hand side.

Comment: You should both your operators outside of the class (make them friends if required). As stated above, you cannot have an operator+ with a char on the lhs unless you define the operator outside of the class.

Comment: See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `operator+` should not modify the current object. It should not return a vector but a new `String<T>`. It should be `const`.

Your `char,int` constuctor misses to add a nullterminator. Maybe that was on purpose, but I changed it because I am using that constructor. Moreover, I removed the move constructor, because its not needed yet. In its implementation you assign `nullptr` to the `vector` which is wrong. You need not implement the move constructor, you can declare it as `=default;`. This is what I also did for the copy constructor, because the compiler generated copy constructor is as good (or better) than your self written one.

Then, there is no `+` for `'e'+String` in your code. When implmented as member then `this` is always the left operand. You can implement it as free function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class String {   
public:
    std::vector<T> ptr_string;
    String() { ptr_string.push_back('\0'); }
    String(const String& other) = default;
    String(T symbol, int n) {    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ptr_string.push_back(symbol);            
        }
        ptr_string.push_back('\0');        
    }
    int getLength() const {
        return ptr_string.size();
    }
    void printString() const {
        int i = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ptr_string.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << ptr_string[i];            
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    template<typename T2>
    auto operator+( T2 b) const { 
        String res = *this;
        res.ptr_string.push_back(b);
        return res;
    }
    auto operator+( String const& a) {
        String res = *this;
        for (const auto& c : a.ptr_string) res.ptr_string.push_back(c);
        return res;
    }
};

template<typename T2,typename T>
auto operator+(const T2& b,const String<T>& a) { 
        return String<T>(b,1) + a;
}

int main() {
    String<char> P = String<char>( 'P', 10);
    auto Y = P + 'e';
    P.printString();
    Y.printString();
    auto Z = 'e' + P;
    P.printString();
    Z.printString();

}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b514Eh37W)

This is just minimum changes on your code. I would actually implement also the other operators outside of the class as free functions. The loop in the `char,int` constructor should be replaced with the appropriate vector constructor and perhaps there is more which can be improved. For more on operator overloading I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators and [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your assignment really cover a scenario that happens in real life. It is full of code smell. As @463035818_is_not_a_number mentionned operator+ usually don't modify the current object. But it is technically possible, See below. Vector are not meant to "push_front", avoid 'push_front' on vector as a general rule (here, i use deque for ex).

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template<class T>
struct ConcatenableDeq
{
    std::deque<T> _deq;

    ConcatenableDeq(std::deque<T> deq) : _deq(deq) {};
         
    void print() const
    {
        for (const auto& e : this->_deq)
            std::cout << e << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    friend void operator+(ConcatenableDeq<T>& cd, const T& v)
    {
        cd._deq.push_back(v);
    }

    friend void operator+(const T& v, ConcatenableDeq<T>& cd)
    {
        cd._deq.push_front(v);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ConcatenableDeq<char> cd({ '1', '2', '3' });

    cd.print();
    cd + '4';
    cd.print();
    '0' + cd;
    cd.print();

    // output:
    // 1 2 3
    // 1 2 3 4
    // 0 1 2 3 4
}
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, but i tried compiling the code and on this line of code it gave an error 
ConcatenableDeq<char> cv({ '1', '2', '3' });
Error C2665 'ConcatenableDeq<char>::ConcatenableDeq': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types 
I don't quite understand what the problem is, so can you suggest what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Dan Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Yes, something about not inheriting the allocator of the deque class.It is probably better not to inherit a std class (i edited my code).But that shows well that adding functionnality to std class is a code smell.